# How to write code for equal button for scientific calculator in GUI by using split string()?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write scientific calculator in Java (GUI). How can I write commands for equal button to consider precedence of *,/,+,- in a string?

```
    String[] st = s.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
            char eql[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= st.length; i++) {
        if ('*' == eql[i]) {
            double a = eql[i + 1] * eql[i - 1];
            jTextField1.setText(a+"");
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input is * || input is /)
    //do multiplication and division left to right
else if (input is + || input is -)
    //do addition and subtraction left to right
```

I will also add that the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://eddmann.com/posts/shunting-yard-implementation-in-java/) could be useful or interesting. Hope this helps!